# EmptyDataTemplate Does not show when Empty

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview that has a EmptyDataTemplate, but it does not show when there is no data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="TransID"
    Font-Size="Small" GridLines="Vertical" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="50"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AllowSorting="True" >
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"
        NextPageText="Next" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransID" HeaderText="Transaction ID" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TransID">
            <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="False" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LicNumFrom" HeaderText="License Number From" SortExpression="LicNumFrom" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LicNameFrom" HeaderText="Name From" SortExpression="LicNameFrom" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LicNumTo" HeaderText="License Number To" SortExpression="LicNumTo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LicNameTo" HeaderText="Name To" SortExpression="LicNameTo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfDelivery" HeaderText="Date Of Delivery" SortExpression="DateOfDelivery"
            DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2D5278" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div>
            No Data Available
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

All it shows is a little square. I've tried putting a Label in the EmptyDataTemplate, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How are you binding the data?  Are you sure there are 0 records and not perhaps an empty record?  What is the actual resulting markup?

Comment: I know it's empty when I run the SQL independently and it returns no data.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? Where does the little X come from?

Comment: Not sure what you mean mason. The code is above and not sure what you mean about little X.

Comment: @user3653252 The "code" above is markup, not code. And it's the server side markup. HTML is generated from the server side markup and sent to the client. Usually if you right click a webpage with your browser you'll have a "View Source" option, where you can see the actual HTML that was sent to the client. Do that, and find the part that corresponds to the little square you mentioned. Then go read about how ASP.NET works, as understanding the difference between server side markup and the HTML that's sent to the client is critical to using it properly.

Comment: <div>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="Center" rules="cols" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Small;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="10"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>

Answer (score 0):

You should check the CSS style of EmptyDataTemplate. It looks like you are getting it in a square box but texts are same as your background color and so they are lost in the background. You are getting that square box because you are applying 1px black border to your GridView which also gets applied to EmptyDataTemplate by default.

Try to apply EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" attribute to your GridView with any color which is not same as GridView background color and check the result.

Comment: I did and I still get the little square.